# Can't add custom postfix completion template

Tags: pycharm

In the settings of PyCharm, under the 'Postfix Completion' tab ('General > 'Postfix Completion'), the 'Add' button for adding a new template is greyed out:

[image]

I have tried both from within an open project and from the welcome screen. I also tried restarting the IDE.

Any idea why, and how to fix this?

#### Additional details

- PyCharm version 2018 2.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not implemented yet. Please vote for this [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30217).